# Finding correlation through plotting logarithms

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

I have a problem in which I am to find the correlation between two sets of data. Plotting them as logarithms makes for a constant increase, except for one of the data points (the first), as seen in the graph below. How do I continue from here? What solution could possibly create a constant increase?

The values for $x$: $0.2, 1.1, 4.4, 8.2, 12.5, 15.1$.

The values for $y$: $2.08, 4.42, 40.7, 136.5, 314.5, 458.0$.

The logarithms of these give the following graph:

[image: The graph of $log(x)$ and $log(y)$.]

Comment: How can we answer that question based on the scant information you have given us? Do you mean you just need to find the line that goes through those points?

Comment: I need to find a correlation between the values that result in the $x$ and $y$ axes. I can edit and add the values, but it's more about understanding how to solve this type of problem, than to solve this specific problem with those specific values.

Comment: I added the values.